# Transparency Key not working on windows 7 basic theme

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a form . I set the backcolor and transparency key of form to limeGreen to make form transparent.

```
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
```

This works fine on window 7 theme but when i changes my theme from windows 7 to windows 7 basic it shows the background of the form ? is there any way i can solve this issue ?

Windows 7 Theme

[image: Windows 7 theme]

Windows 7 Basic Theme

[image: Windows 7 Basic Theme]

Comment: Are you changing the theme while the app is running?

Comment: I am pretty sure that TransparencyKey is a Aero feature only. I remember trying to use it in the past and i chose to go with overriding the onpaint of the form to cut it to my need. Aero is disabled on windows basic theme.

Comment: Just tried a quick test and on my windows XP VM the TransparencyKey does NOT work, it doesn't either on windows 7 pro on basic theme but it does on windows 7 pro with standard theme with Aero enabled. So yes it seems to be Aero feature but i cannot find anything backing this up other than these quick 3 test that point toward that.

Comment: so whats the solution @Franck ?

Comment: yes am changing the theme during application is running @TaW

Comment: So, does it work when you first change theme to basic and then start your app?

Comment: Your top screen shot hints at the core problem, note how a green fringe is visible.  Caused by your painting program emulating anti-aliasing by using per-pixel alpha.  That changes the color of the background pixel, it no longer matches the color key and makes the green fringe visible.  This will extend to the entire image if it is stretched when it is painted.  The interpolation causes the mismatch.  It will only work well if you fix the image and/or draw the image exactly as large as it was designed so no interpolation is necessary.

Comment: @HansPassant nice answer! fixed similar issue and surfing in Internet why it works

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested on Windows 7 without Aero enabled, but this will work 100% on Windows XP:

```
public class XForm : Form
{

    #region Default value overrides

    [DefaultValue(FormStartPosition.Manual)]
    public new FormStartPosition StartPosition
    {
        get { return base.StartPosition; }
        set { base.StartPosition = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(FormBorderStyle.None)]
    public new FormBorderStyle FormBorderStyle
    {
        get { return base.FormBorderStyle; }
        set { base.FormBorderStyle = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public new bool ShowInTaskbar
    {
        get { return base.ShowInTaskbar; }
        set { base.ShowInTaskbar = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LavenderBlush")]
    public new Color TransparencyKey
    {
        get { return base.TransparencyKey; }
        set { base.TransparencyKey = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "LavenderBlush")]
    public new Color BackColor
    {
        get { return base.BackColor; }
        set { base.BackColor = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    public XForm()
        : base()
    {
        // set user paint style
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        // override
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        TransparencyKey = BackColor = Color.LavenderBlush;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // half opaque background
        using (HatchBrush brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent50, this.TransparencyKey))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```

It doesn't makes it completely transparent, but hatched, yet it should be easy to figure out of how to fix it =P

P.S.: a tip, don't use smoothing (by using different colors) or you will have that ugly border around your image (unless it is intended).